# Which S3 API should I use to see the list of buckets owned by me only

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

can you please help me to see the list of buckets owned by me onlyl. I have tried the following api, but it shows all the buckets avaialable in S3. But i want to see only the buckets owned by me not others.

```
aws s3api list-buckets
```

Comment: What do you mean by "owned by me only"? It is by your account, by you as an IAM entity, or what?

Answer (score 1):

An Amazon S3 bucket is always *owned* by an AWS account. Individual IAM Users do *not* own buckets.

When you issue a command such as `aws s3 ls` or `aws s3api list-buckets`, you will only see a list of buckets owned by the account. (It will not list buckets owned by a different account.)

Therefore, that is the correct command.

Comment: if I am not wrong, bucket owner is that user who actually created the bucket. If there are 10 users in the AWS account, then one should not see the buckets created by someone else. isn't it?

Comment: While an IAM User can be designated as the Bucket Owner, that is mostly irrelevant. A bucket belongs to an AWS account and that account can grant access to a bucket via an IAM policy, or by adding a Bucket Policy. When you list buckets, you will see _all buckets in the account_. So, all of your 10 users would see all of the buckets. There is no way to limit this listing -- it's _all or nothing_.